# What are the difference between magento 1 and magento 2 databases?

Tags: magento2, database, magento-1

I want to know what are the difference **between a magento 1 and a magento 2 database** table?

Are there any changes in table names ?

Comment: pls check here https://www.ubertheme.com/magento2/infographic-magento-1-vs-magento-2-database-structure/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see the database diagram then I would suggest you check diagram,

- [Magento 1 Database diagram](http://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png)
- [Magento 2 Database Diaggram](http://anna.voelkl.at/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ce2.1.3.png)

Credit for this awesome diagram goes  to [Anna Völkl](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/231/anna-v%C3%B6lkl)

And she already has written very nice explanation about difference between two databases which you can find it at this [link](http://anna.voelkl.at/magento-ce-2-1-3-database-diagram/)

Source :[Link](http://anna.voelkl.at/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is immense difference between magento 1 and magento 2 database.

Few table names of database are already renamed/replaced in magento 2 database structure. like

> **'core_website' replaced with 'store_website' along with its structure.**

Few fields of tables are removed in magento 2 database structure like -

> **The ‘customer_entity’, ‘customer_address_entity ‘tables removed the
>   ‘entity_type_id’, ‘attribute_set_id’ fields**

**To know the complete difference along with its structure refer this link** - 
https://www.ubertheme.com/magento2/infographic-magento-1-vs-magento-2-database-structure/

Answer (score 0):

Renamed tables (from Magento 1.x to Magento 2.x):

```
core_website - store_website(structure is changed)
core_store - store(structure is not changed)
core_translate - translation
core_url_rewrite - url_rewrite
core_store_group - store_group(structure is not changed)
core_email_template - email_template
admin_role - authorization_role(structure is changed)
admin_rule - authorization_rule(structure is changed)
sales_flat_order - sales_order
sales_flat_order_address - sales_order_address
sales_flat_order_grid - sales_order_grid
sales_flat_order_item - sales_order_item
sales_flat_order_payment - sales_order_payment
sales_flat_order_status_history - sales_order_status_history
coupon_aggregated_order - salesrule_coupon_aggregated_order
```

Magento 2 doesn’t contain the following tables:

```
catalogsearch_query;
catalogsearch_result
catalog_product_enabled_index.
```

Answer (score 0):

This link all changes describe Magento 1 vs Magento 2 Database Structure so please check it

https://www.ubertheme.com/magento2/infographic-magento-1-vs-magento-2-database-structure/

http://www.venustheme.com/magento-2-database-structure/

Name change for some tables.

[image]